# Behaviour of tryLock and lock.tryLock(timeout, unit)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have few doubts regarding tryLock and  lock.tryLock(timeout, unit) function of ReentrantLock.

1. What will happen if two threads are waiting for a lock by calling   lock.tryLock(timeout, unit).And lock is released while both thread are   still waiting(their timeout is not finished yet).My question is which thread will get lock? and what will happen with another waiting thread?
   example:
    at t=0 th1 owns lock
    at t=1 th2 calls lock.tryLock(timeout, unit) for 4 sec
    at t=2 th3 calls lock.tryLock(timeout, unit) for 3 sec
    at t=3 th1 released lock
    i think if lock is fair th2 will get the lock. i am correct?
    what will happen if lock is not fair.and what will happen with  another thread,will that thread wait for remaining time?
2. which method is prior,timed tryLock or untime tryLock.
   example
   at t=0 th1 owns lock
   at t=1 th2 call lock.tryLock(timeout, unit) for 2 sec
   at t=2 th1 releases lock at same time some thread th3 calls   lock.tryLock() which thread th1 or th3 will get lock?

   th* stands a thread.

Answer (score 1):

> i think if lock is fair th2 will get the lock. i am correct?

Yes.  That's what "fair" means:  It means that the first thread to enter the queue will be the first to acquire the lock.

> what will happen if lock is not fair?

It means that the order in which the threads acquire the lock is not required to be the same as the order in which they entered the queue.  They *might* acquire the lock in that order, or they might not.  It's the JVM implementor's choice.  Usually the JVM implementor will try to do something that will maximize the performance of some "typical" application.

> at t=2 th1 releases lock at same time...

There is never any reason to say that two events happen at the same time when you are trying to explain the behavior of multi-threaded programs.  It only complicates the explanation, and it does not provide any deeper insight than if you pretend that it can't happen.

> ...some thread th3 calls lock.tryLock()

The `reentrantLock.tryLock()` method is special.  If the lock is fair, then threads that call `tryLock()` apparently can, under some circumstances, acquire the lock *before* other threads that have been waiting for it.  I do not completely understand the circumstances under which that can happen, but you can read about it in the Javadoc:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock() (search for the word, "barging".)

If th2 is waiting for the lock when th1 releases it, there apparently is some window of time during which th3 can "barge in" with `tryLock()` and acquire it before th2 gets the chance.  I do not know how that window of time is defined.

Note that `reentrantLock.tryLock(n)` does *not* have that same "barging" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. first call to the lock.tryLock(timeout,unit) under fair ordering poicy. According to 
   [tryLock - Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29),

> Acquires the lock if it is not held by another thread and returns immediately with the value true, setting the lock hold count to one. **If this lock has been set to use a fair ordering policy then an available lock will not be acquired if any other threads are waiting for the lock**. This is in contrast to the tryLock() method. If you want a timed tryLock that does permit barging on a fair lock then combine the timed and un-timed forms together: 
>   `if (lock.tryLock() || lock.tryLock(timeout, unit) ) { ... }`

2. th3 will have the lock

> Acquires the lock if it is not held by another thread and returns immediately with the value true, setting the lock hold count to one. **Even when this lock has been set to use a fair ordering policy, a call to tryLock() will immediately acquire the lock if it is available, whether or not other threads are currently waiting for the lock.** This "barging" behavior can be useful in certain circumstances, even though it breaks fairness. If you want to honor the fairness setting for this lock, then use tryLock(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS) which is almost equivalent (it also detects interruption).